# detects a value from a multiplied combo box

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to detects a value from a multiplied combo box?
when I change value one of combo box become "2" the component is show
but when I change the value of another multiplied combo box become besides "2" 
the component hide directly. And I won't its happen

**I want, if there still exist value 2 the component isn't hide directly**

this is function to multiply the combo box

```
function addEmploy() {}
    $('#addEmploy').click(function(){
        $('#comboEmploy')
        .append('<br />')
        .append($('#comboEmploy select').first().clone(true));
    });
```

this is script to show or hide the component

```
$("#employ").change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "2"){
            $("#comboStudy").show("slow");
        }else{
            $("#comboStudy").hide("slow");
        }
    });
```

This is the combo box

```
<span id="comboEmploy">
                <select name="employ[]" id="employ">
                    <option value="NULL" selected >Choose one</option>
                    <?php foreach ($employs as $employ) :?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $employ->employ_id; ?>">
                        <?php echo $employ->employ_name; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            </span>
<a href="#" id="addEmploy">Add Employ</a>
```

This is the component that I want to show/hide

```
<span id="comboStudy">
            <select name="study[]" id="study">
                <option selected value=NULL>Choose one</option>
                <?php foreach ($studies as $study) :?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $study->study_id; ?>">
                        <?php echo $study->study_name; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            </span>
```

Can anyone help me. thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is due to the fact that your #employee.change handler is attached to all of your select boxes.  This way, if any of them is changed to something other than 2 it will hide.  What you need to do in this change handler is check all of your select boxes (not just the one that changed) and see if any one of them contains a 2.  You then only hide if none of them had 2.

In addition, IDs should be unique.  When you clone your select box you should change the ID.

Comment: how to change the id with JS..?

Comment: yeah, create a variable and increment it or something

Comment: Is there any other way than to differentiate id..?

Comment: I've differentiate the ID,
how to check all of select boxes that contains 2..?

Comment: Probably the best way would be to assign them all the same class and then do something like this :  `$(".myselect").is("[value='2']")` see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sb5mc/